# How to fix vscode icon in numix icon circle theme?

Tags: icon-themes, numix

Due to the generic `code` name, the Numix team have decide not to use the `code.desktop` icon provided by the VS Code package.

So it's icon is configured as a common text editor by default.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like that the Numix team has provided [an alternative icon](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-core/issues/2964) with the name of `vscode.desktop`, in order to fix it we need to:

1. Copy and rename the default `code.desktop` to the local user directory:

`cp /usr/share/applications/code.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications/vscode.desktop`

2. Edit the new `vscode.desktop` and rename all `Icon` properties from `Icon=code` to `Icon=vscode`.

The result should be something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --unity-launch %U
Icon=vscode
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
Actions=new-window;
Keywords=vscode;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Name[de]=Neues Fenster
Name[es]=Nueva ventana
Name[fr]=Nouvelle fenêtre
Name[it]=Nuova finestra
Name[ja]=新規ウインドウ
Name[ko]=새 창
Name[ru]=Новое окно
Name[zh_CN]=新建窗口
Name[zh_TW]=開新視窗
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --new-window %U
Icon=vscode
```

3. Restart the session to apply the new icon.

Comment: The answer from @gvsrepins work for me. But I did the Icon name change in the /usr/share/applications/code.desktop with root permission right there instead of duplicating it in the ~/.local/share/applications/ directory. This prevents it from showing duplicate icon in the application list.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try editing /usr/share/applications/code.desktop directly instead.

Comment: Note: you can use `sudo desktop-file-install vscode.desktop` to update the icon without logging in and back out.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a one liner that will achieve what these guys are saying for you. I've aliased this in bash because I have to execute this every FREAKING time vscode updates...

```
sudo sed -i "s/Icon=code/Icon=vscode/g" /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely sure Visual Studio Code will be the only 'code' executable,

just copying the vscode.svg icon seems to be a better solution

as it'll also theme the icon if you launch vscode via terminal command: code.

```
sudo ln -s visualstudiocode.svg /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps/code.svg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Answer (score 0):

This little script should do the job. Since a copy is placed in `.local/share`, it shouldn't be changed when apt upgrades. (Here the Numix-Icon-Circle is choosen.)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: change the vs-code icon to the specific numix icon

cp /usr/share/applications/code.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/code.desktop
sed -i "s/Icon=\/usr\/share\/pixmaps\/com.visualstudio.code.png/Icon=\/usr\/share\/icons\/Numix-Circle\/48\/apps\/vscode.svg/g" ~/.local/share/applications/code.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

go to :

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/code.desktop
```

and change

```
Icon=vscode
```

to

```
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/com.visualstudio.code.png
```